# Regex match only if element doesn't start with '('

Tags: javascript, regex

I've got an app that uses song titles as strings.  One of the problems is that some song titles include the artist's name and their remix.  For example:

```
RAC - Lana Del Rey Blue Jeans (RAC Mix)
```

I ultimately would like the string to look like this:

```
Lana Del Rey Blue Jeans (RAC Mix)
```

I understand that I can do a simple `String.replace('-','')` to remove the dashes but I'm wondering if somebody could help me use a regex to get rid of the artist names **only if they don't start with a** `(`.  I want to keep the `(RAC Mix)`

I'm very new to regex and I'm having a hard time figuring this out.  I've been playing around on https://regex101.com/#javascript but with no luck.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: provide more comprehensive examples of actual song-titles and desired outputs

Comment: `'RAC - Lana Del Rey Blue Jeans (RAC Mix)'.replace(/^[^-]+-\s*/, '')`

Comment: The first example I show is an actual song title. "RAC - Lana Del Rey Blue Jeans (RAC Mix)".  I want it to be shortened to "Lana Del Rey Blue Jeans (RAC Mix)"

Comment: I really don't understand your requirements. How do you know that `RAC -` is an artist name?

Comment: @falsetru That does what I'm looking for although I've modified it slightly to search directly for the artist name as opposed to just beginning at the start of the string.  This is because sometimes the start of the string doesn't have the correct artist and I need to handle that differently.  If you'd like, you can post the answer here and I'll mark it as correct.

Comment: @ruakh Because I can cross reference the title of the song with the actual artist name in the database, however sometimes the title also include the artist name again.

Comment: @user3669257: "I can cross reference the title of the song with the actual artist name in the database" does not sound like a regex question. (Regexes don't support database lookups.)

Comment: @ruakh I'm not using a regex for database lookups.  Please see the accepted answer below.  I've made an edit to that answer to explain my usage.  Once the edit is accepted you'll be able to see where I was going with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following regular expression to remove leading artist name (assuming artists name comes first and is separated from title by `-`):

```
/^[^-]+-\s*/
```

---

```
'RAC - Lana Del Rey Blue Jeans (RAC Mix)'.replace(/^[^-]+-\s*/, '')
// => "Lana Del Rey Blue Jeans (RAC Mix)"
```

---

EDIT:

I am using this regex `/RAC[^-]-+\s*/`.  The first portion of the regex is variable in my code and thus would work for other song titles such as:

```
var artistname = 'coldplay';
var re = new RegEx(artistname + '[^-]-+\\s*');
'Coldplay - Yellow (Coldplay Mix)'.replace(re, '');
# => 'Yellow (Coldplay Mix)'
```

Answer (score 1):

You could completely avoid `RegExp` if you wanted.  Here's a different way to look at it:

```js
function stripArtist(str) {
  var i = str.indexOf('-');

  //assumes there is a space after "-"
  if (~i) {
    return str.slice(i + 1);
  } else {
    return str;
  }
}

var div = document.getElementById('song');
div.innerHTML = stripArtist(div.innerHTML);
```

```html
<div>RAC - Lana Del Rey Blue Jeans (RAC Mix)</div>
<div id="song">RAC - Lana Del Rey Blue Jeans (RAC Mix)</div>
```

Comment: I understand what this does however this won't work in my case because I don't always want to remove everything before the `-`.  Sometimes I want to keep it hence the reason I'm going with a regex.

Comment: Then I don't think we would be able to tell you much without that more info.  If you strip the `-` first, there would be nothing separating an artist name from the title.